# NEST 7 Query.Raw(rawJson) giving me Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful (400) low level call on POST

Tags: c#, json, .net, elasticsearch, nest

Code i am using to perform search against Elasticsearch

```
string q2 = "{\"query\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"fuzzy\":{\"name\":{\"value\":\"zeorgia\",\"max_expansions\":\"1\"}}}],\"must_not\":[],\"should\":[]}},\"from\":0,\"size\":50,\"sort\":[],\"aggs\":{ }}";


ISearchResponse<Responder> response2 = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<Responder>(s => s.Query(qry => qry.Raw(q2))).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Getting the below error

```
Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful (400) low level call on POST: /xyz-idx/_search?typed_keys=true
```

## Audit trail of this API call:

- [1] BadResponse: Node: https://example.com/ Took: 00:00:01.2080980

## OriginalException: Elasticsearch.Net.ElasticsearchClientException: Request failed to execute. Call: Status code 400 from: POST /xyz-idx/_search?typed_keys=true. ServerError: Type: parsing_exception Reason: "unknown query [query]" CausedBy: "Type: named_object_not_found_exception Reason: "[1:19] unknown field [query]""

## Request:

<Request stream not captured or already read to completion by serializer. Set DisableDirectStreaming() on ConnectionSettings to force it to be set on the response.>

## Response:

<Response stream not captured or already read to completion by serializer. Set DisableDirectStreaming() on ConnectionSettings to force it to be set on the response.>

OriginalException = {"Request failed to execute. Call: Status code 400 from: POST /xyz-idx/_search?typed_keys=true. ServerError: Type: parsing_exception Reason: "unknown query [query]" CausedBy: "Type: named_object_not_found_exception Reason: "[1:19] unknown field [q...

Request failed to execute. Call: Status code 400 from: POST /xyz-idx/_search?typed_keys=true. ServerError: Type: parsing_exception Reason: "unknown query [query]" CausedBy: "Type: named_object_not_found_exception Reason: "[1:19] unknown field [query]""

Comment: I am using dot net web api with NEST 7 package.

Seems like json is not properly converted i guess, could you please help me to find the solution for this problem!

Comment: Any specific reason you are using the raw query? Also, did you try executing this query through your kibana interface before triggering it via `NEST`?

Comment: Basically i am designing an dot net web API which is taking raw json (query dsl) as input, from there i am passing to elasticsearchClient to perform search.

Comment: the function in NEST 7 library is like below

       //
        // Summary:
        //     A query defined using a raw json string.
        //     The query must be enclosed within '{' and '}'
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   rawJson:
        //     The query dsl json
        public QueryContainer Raw(string rawJson);

Comment: yeah i have verified in postman by pointing to the direct elastic search rest api by providing the json (plain, does not contains '/' and any other specials characters)

{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"fuzzy":{"name":{"value":"zeorgia","max_expansions":"1"}}}],"must_not":[],"should":[]}},"from":0,"size":50,"sort":[],"aggs":{}}

And working as we expected, but dot net web api + NEST 7 is not able to doing the job

Comment: I have to pass the below query (raw) to NEST client by removing the query attribute in json. for example like the below 

{"bool":{"must":[{"fuzzy":{"name":{"value":"bank"}}}],"must_not":[],"should":[]}}

not like

{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"fuzzy":{"name":{"value":"bank"}}}],"must_not":[],"should":[]}},"from":0,"size":10,"sort":[],"aggs":{}}

Comment: Thank you @SaiGummaluri for suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

The raw query should be the JSON object that would be assigned to the `"query"` property i.e.

```cs
var searchResponse = client.Search<MyDocument>(s => s
    .Index("index_name,cluster_two:index_name")
    .Query(q => q
        .Raw("{\"fuzzy\":{\"name\":{\"value\":\"bank\"}}}")
    )
);
```

which would be equivalent to

```cs
var searchResponse = client.Search<MyDocument>(s => s
    .Index("index_name,cluster_two:index_name")
    .Query(q => q
        .Fuzzy(f => f
            .Field("name")
            .Value("bank")
        )
    )
);
```